# Append empty table rows to a table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I output a table when the user selects something. I have a button that will allow the user to append an empty table row to the end of the table but I can't seem to get it working properly.

HTML generation code in PHP:

```
echo<table>
   "<table id='roof-component-data-table'><tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Roof Component</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>";tr>
        <tr id="roofComponentRow" style="display: none;">
        //empty row used to clone<td><input type="text" id="roof-component-name" name="roof-component-name[]" value="" <="" td=""></td>
        echo</tr>
 "<tr id='roofComponentRow' style='display: none;'>";    <tr id="roofComponentRow0">
        echo "<td><input type='text' id='roof <td><input type="text" id="roof-component-name'name" name='roofname="roof-component-name[]'name[]" value=''<value="Air Film" <="" td=""></td>";td>
        echo "<   <td><a href="#" class="removeRoofComponentRow" onclick="removeRoofComponent("Air Film")">Delete</tr>";a></td>
        </tr>
        while<tr ($roofComponentsRowid="roofComponentRow1">
 = mysqli_fetch_array($roofComponentsData)) {         <td><input type="text" id="roof-component-name" name="roof-component-name[]" value="Surfacing" <="" td=""></td>
            echo<td><a "<trhref="#" id='roofComponentRow".class="removeRoofComponentRow" $ComponentRowCounteronclick="removeRoofComponent("Surfacing")">Delete</a></td>
 ."'>";       </tr>
        <tr id="roofComponentRow2">
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='roof     <td><input type="text" id="roof-component-name'name" name='roofname="roof-component-name[]'name[]" value='".value="Membranes" $roofComponentsRow['roof_component_name']<="" ."'<td=""></td>";td>
            echo "<td><a<td><a href='#'href="#" class='removeRoofComponentRow'class="removeRoofComponentRow" onClick='removeRoofComponentonclick="removeRoofComponent(\"{$roofComponentsRow['roof_component_name']}\""Membranes")'>Delete<">Delete</a></td>";td>
        </tr>
        echo<tr "<id="roofComponentRow3">
            <td><input type="text" id="roof-component-name" name="roof-component-name[]" value="Overlay Boards" <="" td=""></tr>";td>
            <td><a href="#" class="removeRoofComponentRow" onclick="removeRoofComponent("Overlay Boards")">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    $ComponentRowCounter++;    <tr id="roofComponentRow4">
        }    <td><input type="text" id="roof-component-name" name="roof-component-name[]" value="Insulation" <="" td=""></td>
echo "<           <td><a href="#" class="removeRoofComponentRow" onclick="removeRoofComponent("Insulation")">Delete</table>";a></td>
        </tr>
echo"<input type='button' value='+' id='addRoofComponentRow' class='addRoofComponentRow'</>";tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" value="+" id="addRoofComponentRow" class="addRoofComponentRow">
```

This is what my table looks like:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Roof Component</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="roofComponentRow" style="display: none;">
            <td><input type="text" id="roof-component-name" name="roof-component-name[]" value="" <="" td=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="roofComponentRow0">
            <td><input type="text" id="roof-component-name" name="roof-component-name[]" value="Air Film" <="" td=""></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="removeRoofComponentRow" onclick="removeRoofComponent("Air Film")">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="roofComponentRow1">
            <td><input type="text" id="roof-component-name" name="roof-component-name[]" value="Surfacing" <="" td=""></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="removeRoofComponentRow" onclick="removeRoofComponent("Surfacing")">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="roofComponentRow2">
            <td><input type="text" id="roof-component-name" name="roof-component-name[]" value="Membranes" <="" td=""></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="removeRoofComponentRow" onclick="removeRoofComponent("Membranes")">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="roofComponentRow3">
            <td><input type="text" id="roof-component-name" name="roof-component-name[]" value="Overlay Boards" <="" td=""></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="removeRoofComponentRow" onclick="removeRoofComponent("Overlay Boards")">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="roofComponentRow4">
            <td><input type="text" id="roof-component-name" name="roof-component-name[]" value="Insulation" <="" td=""></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="removeRoofComponentRow" onclick="removeRoofComponent("Insulation")">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" value="+" id="addRoofComponentRow" class="addRoofComponentRow">
```

Now when the user clicks the `+` button it will fire off some JS that should clone my empty row and append it to the end of the table.

Here is how I am attempting to do that:

```
$(function() {

    var $removeIDValue = 0;

    $(document.body).on('click', '.addRoofComponentRow', function () {

        var $emptyRoofComponentRow = $("#roofComponentRow").clone();
        $removeIDValue++

        var $emptyRoofComponentRowClone = $emptyRoofComponentRow.clone();
        var $newRowID = 'added_roof_component_row' + $removeIDValue;
        $emptyRoofComponentRowClone.attr('id', $newRowID)
        $emptyRoofComponentRowClone.children('td').last().after('<td><a href="#" class="removeRow" data-remove-row="' + $newRowID + '">Delete</a></td>');

        $('#roof-component-data-table').append($emptyRoofComponentRowClone);
        $emptyRoofComponentRowClone.show();
    });
});
```

When I click the button nothing is happening at all, I see nothing being added onto the table and I am getting no console errors at all. I also set an alert with that function to see if the function was even firing and my alert message did get displayed.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr1g02go/)

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: instead of posting the php, could you please post the rendered html. A fiddle would be useful too

Comment: @andrew only html now, and added a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function will work alright I guess, only there are three issues here:

1. the table that is selected cannot be selected, since the rendered table has no `id`. **This is the biggest problem with this code**.
2. `echo "<td><input type='text' id='roof-component-name' name='roof-component-name[]' value=''</td>";` In this line the input isn't closed resulting in badly formed HTML.
3. In the HTML generation the delete link doesn't has escaped quotes, generating script errors.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dr1g02go/4/

Comment: 1. I clone the first row of another table exactly like this and I am getting no issues?

2. I added in the `true` argument within the clone function.

3. I fixed the closing bracket here.

Comment: deep clone has nothing to do with including children. Item #2 is incorrect

Comment: @charlietfl, you are right, mixed it with `element.prototype.clone` which by default doesn't make a deep copy.

Comment: @Mouser got it all working, thanks for the other fixes as well - helped me out quite a bit! :)

Answer (score 3):

youre not appending it to anything

add `<tbody id="roof-component-data-table">`

https://jsfiddle.net/dr1g02go/5/